# QGIS 3.10 WMS links location

Tags: qgis, wms

I would like to remove all wms layer from Data Source Manager?

Is it possible to do it all at once?

I have a lot of wms servers added.
When I try to import short list it is added to the existing list.
Maybe there is a file containing this data.

I know how to export, import, but how to remove all at once?

*Edit:*
It worked very good! I opened the file in Notepad and removed all lines with "connection-wms". After that I have added new list of WMS.
I am really greatful for your help! I hate to have a mess.

Comment: They are stored in the qgis3.ini file look for  'connections-wms' (backup your file before editing) [Windows] C:\Users\{pcname}\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS

Comment: or `/home/{user}/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/` [Ubuntu]